# Index notation and total differential

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, differentiation, notation

I understand that the gradient $\partial_i$ is covariant.
Let f be a function of 3 variables
So I can write the total differential as
$$
df=\partial_1fdx^1+\partial_2fdx^2+\partial_3fdx^3 = \partial_kfdx^k,
$$
summing correctly over the same lower and upper index.
But when I write
$
\displaystyle\partial_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}
$ (and this is how it is written in all books)
and want to write the total differential, I have to write
$$
df= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^1}dx^1+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^2}dx^2+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^3}dx^3=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}dx^k
$$
and so I am summing over the same upper indices.

My question: Why does an index get raised when it is moved to the denominator?

Comment: Isn't this asking "why is the gradient covariant?", which you claim to understand in the first sentence?

Comment: No, it is not. I want to know why the index gets raised in the denominator

Comment: I think the logic flows in the opposite sense: $f(x^1, x^2, x^3, x^4)$ is a function of contravariant components. When we expand it as a differential, the invariance of $df$ requires that the gradient is covariance, and hense the index must be lowered.

Comment: raised compared to what? The gradient is normally defined as the derivative wrt the components $x^i$, which in the usual notation for partial derivatives is denoted $\partial/\partial x^i$.

Comment: Sorry, I had not seen these 2 answers before. Vadim, I understand that the index is lowered. What I do not understand is, why the index is raised again when we write it in the form $\partial/\partial x^i$.

Comment: I might have a glue. If I write $\partial/\partial x^i$ then $x^i$ is the name of the variable, and this expression is not index notation. If I write $\partial_idx^i$ it is index notation and Einstein's summation applies. If I write $\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}dx^i$ it should not be summed, because Einstein's summation does not apply, but  it is done anyway

Comment: Sorry if I came off as condescending, I could not answer because I do not understand what the crux of the question is. I think with your last comment you are in the right direction.

Comment: no sweats, fqq, I am a bit tickelish because it gets on my nerve that I don't get the answer

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ is also used within Einstein's summation convention, as the covariant components of the gradient, exactly the same as $\partial_i$, which is equivalent notation AFAIK

Comment: Thanks to all who answered, especially to jgerber who hit the nail on the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\partial_i$ is *defined* as $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$. Therefore the index does not get raised when brought to the denominator, rather it is notation for the derivative justified rigorously:

In Cartesian coordinates the partial derivative transforms as a covariant vector
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{x}^i}=\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial \bar{x}^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$$

Covariant vectors are written with lowered indices.

Answer (score 1):

A raised index in the denominator counts as a lowered index (because it is in the denominator)

See "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" by J. Lee. I believe it is in both editions but in the second edition see Chapter 3 on tangent vectors and look at the text below Eq. 3.2:

> $$D_v |_a f = v^i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(a)$$
> (Here we are using the summation convention as usual, so the expression on the right-hand side is understood to be summed over $i=1, \ldots, n$. This sum is consistent with our index convention if we stipulate that an upper index "in the denominator" is to be regarded as a lower index.)

Here $D_v|_a$ is the derivative of function $f$ in the direction of vector $v = v^i e_i|_a$ at point $a$ where $v^i$ are the components of $v$ with respect to the basis $e_i|_a$, where the basis $e_i|_a$ is defined at point $a$.

Lee goes on to introduce the concept of *derivations* and how they can be used to generally define tangent vectors on manifolds. It turns out that the map:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\big|_a
$$

defined by

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\big|_a\left(f\right) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(a)
$$

is a derivation and can be thought of as a tangent vector. Since we agreed above that something like $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ is to be thought of as a `lower index thing' we can equate it with another lower index thing and define

$$
\partial_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}
$$

Comment: Thanks, but I don't remember that any of my beginners relativity books say that explicitely. Does it follow from $x_i=g_{ij}x^j$ or similar? Or, alternatively, can you name a book (lecture text)

Comment: fqq, can you be a bit more helpful? If it helps I can claim that I might not have understood what I claimed I did

Comment: I've edited to add a reference and some extra information.

Comment: @Jagerber48 Hi I'm a bit confused, are you sure this statement at the start of your answer is correct: "A raised index in the denominator counts as a lowered index (because it is in the denominator)"? If true then say Hamilton's equations will be $\dot q_i=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p^i }$ and $\dot p_i=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q^i }$ but everywhere I've seen them they look like $\dot q_i=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_i }$ and $\dot p_i=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q_i }$ like [here](https://galileoandeinstein.phys.virginia.edu/7010/CM_06_HamiltonsEqns.html)

Comment: @Electra yes, a raised index in the denominator counts as a lowered index when using differential geometry covariant/contravariant notation. The reference you linked looks like it is just using $i$ as a standard index not to indicate covariance or contravariance. You'll notice there are NO upper indices on that whole webpage.